# Streaming data into DB

Tags: database, awk, sed, streaming

can you please suggest if there any method to stream data into DB?
I am getting continuously alarms from the source using socket and I need output to be parsed (which is quite easy to do with awk or sed) and then insert every newly appeared data in DB.

So I am wondering if there any way to make it work continuously, I.e. - new records received - it is parsed and inserted into DB.

Can anyone give I clue how to make it?

> <+++> Sn  =  12345 NeSn  =  123123123 ObjFdn  = 
>   NE=1111, eNodeBSctpLink=1111 ObjName  =  Link No.=1111 ObjType  = 
>   SCTPLink NeFdn  =  NE=11111 NeName  =  NEName NeType  =  Network
>   Element 1 AlarmID  =  111111 AlarmName  =   Link Fault Category  = 
>   Fault Severity  =  Major State  =  Unacknowledged  EventType  = 
>   System Occurtime  =  2017-04-05 15:06:07 ClearTime  =  2017-04-05
>   15:08:03 Location  =  Link No.=1111111111111 <--->

Comment: Sounds like a job for a shell script loop: 1. Test if new records 2. If new records, parse them and insert into DB. 3. Sleep for a while 4. Goto 1. Other than that, with the info you provided its pretty hard to go any deeper into the details.

Comment: maybe some extra info needed: what do you receive (form and format like file text, csv + little sample) and where to insert and with which tool avalaible (could be a curl http POST, a isql command line, ....) + minimum info (attribut and expected format, ...)

Comment: Messages coming like that, it has specified format which will not be changed:
<+++>
Sn  =  12345
NeSn  =  123123123
ObjFdn  =  NE=1111,eNodeBSctpLink=1111
ObjName  =  Link No.=1111
ObjType  =  SCTPLink
NeFdn  =  NE=11111
NeName  =  NEName
NeType  =  Network Element 1
AlarmID  =  111111
AlarmName  =   Link Fault
Category  =  Fault
Severity  =  Major
State  =  Unacknowledged 
EventType  =  System
Occurtime  =  2017-04-05 15:06:07
ClearTime  =  2017-04-05 15:08:03
Location  =  Link No.=1111111111111
<--->

Comment: Can you somehow pipe the input into a tool or script? I.e. have you solved the input acquisition or is that part of the question? If that is not part of the question, it should be part of your MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve